# OrCAD Capture Question: Two traces in same plot - where do they cross?

Tags: simulation, orcad

If I have two traces in the same simulation plot, is there a way that I can determine when they are equal to each other?

Comment: Are you talking about wires in Capture, or traces in a PCB layout?

Comment: I think he might be talking about PSPICE simulations

Comment: @Jim, that makes sense.  In that case, plot the difference and look for the point at which it is zero

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; yes, this is a simulation question. There isn't a set way to do that?